# How to add an autoimport to WebStorm Live Templates

Tags: webstorm, live-templates

I have a live template `useS` for

```
const [$VAR1$, set$VAR2$] = useState($END$);
```

where `useState` is an external variable that has to be imported like so:

```
import { useState } from "react";
```

Whenever this template is used, the import should be automatically added to the current file at the top.

The template is used within JS functions, therefore I can not just add an import to the live template, since the import will be placed inline then.

Is there a special pattern for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't work currently, please follow [WEB-37425](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37425/Importable-state-after-Live-Template-insertion) for updates